# Bootstrap is not loading when @Html.ActionLink is clicked but passed parameter is retrieved, The bootstrap is working with other ActionLinks

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to work in an update function where there is a list of documents on my index and in every row there is a link for a update function. The problem is when I try to click the Update link the view successfully retrieves the parameter but my bootstrap seems to load and my view is just a standard HTML page with no CSS.

I have already tried changing the overloads of the method `@Html.ActionLink` but nothing seems to solve the issue.

Code Snippet from Index.cshtml:

```
<td>  
    @Html.ActionLink("Update", "AddOrEdit", "Receiving", new { id = 
    @item.ReceivingDocumentNo.ToString() }, null)
</td>
```

The results should be that the value of `@item.ReceivingDocumentNo.ToString()` should be passed to the controller and as well as the bootstrap layout should be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing null with {@class = "btn btn-primary"} to view button bootstrap